# What core strengthening exercises put the least pressure on the lower back?

Tags: strength, injury-prevention, core

I'm looking for effective exercises to strengthen the entire core while minimizing stress and flexing on the lower back.

No exercises recommended here will be performed without a doctor's approval so please make recommendations freely.

Comment: "Those who have undergone spinal fusion surgery" is far too broad of a term for anyone here to answer. GO SEE A DOCTOR!

Comment: Two vertebrate in the lower back were fused which slightly reduces flexibility making a traditional sit up difficult. I was hoping to find alternative exercises. There is no reason to see a doctor and I would thank you not to yell.

Comment: Sorry for being loud. But I have to insist. If you need to specify that there is a back injury involved, then it is a medical issue. Worst case scenario; we propose a set of exercises that end up being catastrophic. That's why such questions are only fit for those with medical training, be it a doctor or a physical therapist.

Comment: To some extent, by the time a human reaches 50 or 60 they have medical issues that affect their physical fitness routines. It's a little much to say that we're excluding that population from any questions and answers.

Comment: I understand Alec, thanks. I realize no one here wants to offer any advice that may cause harm. I see that "spinal fusion surgery" sounds a bit alarming. I'll modify my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you wrote the core, that would mean also obliques etc.

However, here are some exercises you could do:

- hanging knee raises and as progression leg raises.
  http://www.muscleandfitness.com/workouts/abs-exercises/videos/hanging-knee-raise
- turkish get ups (you can use a dumbbell instead of a kettlebell or a weight plate)
  http://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/turkish_get_up_training.htm
- standing cable crunches as the kneeling  ones are making too much pressure on lower spine.
- hand stands against a wall for time instead of military presses because of potential wrong technique and causing  pressure on lower back - squeeze your but and abs during the hold.
- side bends
  http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/Obliques/DBSideBend.html

take care and do the exercises with caution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your condition is, but an exercise not very taxing on the spine for core (mostly abs) would be: cable crunch (http://www.bodybuilding.com/exercises/detail/view/name/cable-crunch)

EDIT: But you should check with a doctor for sure!

Keep up the good work!

Comment: If done kneeling, it could happen that you are causing too much pressure on lower back - if done wrong or with higher reps as one gets weaker during a set